# sending post data from Iphone

Tags: post, iphone

I want to send post data from Iphone.
I have to send a dictionary(K-V pairs) with 8 k-v pairs.
What is the best way to post all these 8 K-V pairs from Iphone.
I want that i should pass only Id(one of K-V pair)in the URL & remaining K-V pairs should be sent via post.
if there is something like that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a couple blog posts using NSURLConnection. One was specifically for sending POST data. Check them out. You can't send some data with GET and some data with POST. You have to commit to all one way.

[Sending POST DATA](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/sending-post-data-using-nsurlconnection/)

[Using NSURLConnection](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/using-nsurlconnection/)

HTH

Comment: Hi...thanks for replying.
Actually i have a SignUp form in my Iphone application & i want to save all the information(Id,Fname,Lname,Gender,Address,..etc)from
Iphone to Sqlserver.
so i want to discuss you that for the above i have to pass all these values??
it does't look odd to pass more than 10 values??

Comment: it looks odd, but it works. You probably should create  a loop to create the post data string from your K-V pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol doesn't work like that. Pick POST or GET.
This library makes web requests easy, including file upload: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Hi...thanks for replying. Actually i have a SignUp form in my Iphone application & i want to save all the information(Id,Fname,Lname,Gender,Address,..etc)from Iphone to Sqlserver. so i want to discuss you that for the above i have to pass all these values?? it does't look odd to pass more than 10 values??