# send string from iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sending post data from Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499663/sending-post-data-from-iphone)

Hello everyone, I'm a new member of the forum and browsing the web I found what was right for me, or rather being a novice I did not understand what poker was.

What I'm trying to do is go to my iphone from a string php server, example: site.com/site.php?val1=1&val2=2 and that the server will recognize it and give me back a xml, but one thing at a time how do I send the string to the server by pressing a button IBAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I usually do for that:

```
NSString *reqURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://site.com/site.php?val1=%@&val2=%@",var1,var2];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURL]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
```

Comment: why it say unused variable 'response' ?

Comment: Because response is the variable that holds the NSData that is returned from your get request. You can do whatever you want with it. Like convert it to an NSString for example.

Comment: suppose that I am able to get the code, once sent the string php (? lat = 11 etc) it gives me three parameters that are in xml
<lat> 11 </ lat> <lon> 10 </ lon> <imei> 12 </ imei>. (I tested by putting the string in the browser and it works)
What should I do, that is, from what I understand NSData is the one that contains my "answer" right? Suppose you wanted to make a NSLog everything to see if it works. how could I do?

Comment: `NSString *myString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];` Then do whatever you want with the string.

Answer (score 0):

Readup in NSURLConnection or use ASIHttpRequest (which is easier to use).

Answer (score 0):

get ASIHTTPRequest from http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions
and

import

```
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
```

and do following to get response

```
NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://site.com/site.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"val1"];
request setPostValue:@"2" forKey:@"val2"];
[request startSynchronous];
NSString *retVal = nil;
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    retVal = [request responseString];
}
```

here you got data on retVal

Comment: maybe this is not my way, once i've insert the new file i got 30 warning :(

Comment: did you follow the instructions? did you add CFNetwork.framework,SystemConfiguration.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework, CoreGraphics.framework and libz.1.2.3.dylib ? ASIHTTP is best wrapper I found ever